# Upgrading rails 3.0.0 to 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please help me that how to upgrade rails 3.0.0 to rails 3.2.13.
This is my GemFile and what changes are to be made here?

```
# Edit this Gemfile to bundle your application's dependencies.
# This preamble is the current preamble for Rails 3 apps; edit as needed.
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
#gem 'parseexcel'
gem 'will_paginate', ">=3.0.pre", :require => 'will_paginate'
gem 'gbarcode',:git =>'git://github.com/cameroncox/gbarcode.git',:branch =>'ruby1.9'
gem "pg"
gem "attr_encrypted"
gem "spreadsheet", "~> 0.7.5"
#gem "spreadsheet-excel"
#gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
#gem "dynamic_form"    this is for depricate the "error_message for " helper in rails 3
gem 'time_diff', '0.3.0'
gem "fastercsv"
gem 'rails-dev-boost', :git =>  'git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git', :require =>  'rails_development_boost'
#gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", :require => "simple_captcha"
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the changes from Rails 3 to 3.2.x aren't only the Gems.
It was also introduced the assets pipeline and some other changes.
**Edit** I was wrong about it, actually the assets pipeline was introduced on Rails 3.1.

Ryan Bates has a really nice screencast about this upgrade
http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2

I would also recommend you to read the release notes, to get a better understand of rails 3.2 capabilities. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html **Edit** And also the release notes for 3.1 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html

I hope it helps.